# What do you do with a ketubah document following a divorce?

Tags: halacha, divorce, disposal, ketubah

What is the preferred handling of a ketubah following a divorce? It seems wrong to just throw it away. Should it be buried? Is it permissible to burn it?

Comment: Do you say that it feels wrong to throw it away because it is often a piece of art besides being simply a contract? How would you feel about throwing away a ketubah if it were just written on a piece of paper?

Answer (score 6):

The document itself is given to the husband to prove that he actually paid the כתובה. He can dispose of it however he desires. Or alternatively, she gives him a שובר (a receipt) documenting that he actually paid her, and she can do with the כתובה whatever she pleases.

Comment: Seems reasonable; do you have a source for this?

Comment: nothing that i can point to at this second. however, it is simply assumed in the fourth and on perakim of kesubos.

Answer (score 1):

The *ketubah* is merely a prenuptial agreement and once the husband has paid what he promised it is an expired document which the husband can throw away or burn.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: the husband. See the other answer. The rules he cites for handling the ketubah are actually true for any contract that obligates one person to pay another.

Comment: Seems reasonable; do you have a source for this?